# How to Program a jump properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to make the jumping mechanics for a 3d PS1-Style collectathon platformer and Im trying to get the jumps to be like mario where the longer you hold the jump button the heigher you jump.
but I just cant seem to get the factional jumps to work. it ALWAYS ends up being the exact same floaty jumps that reaches a max point and then falls.

any ideas asto what im doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement Things")]
    [Min(1)]
    public int characterSpeed = 1;
    [Min(2.5f)]
    public float jumpPower = 5.0f;
    [Min(0.05f)]
    public float gravity = 2.5f;
 
    private float checkdistance = 5.5f;
    private Rigidbody character;
    private bool isgrounded;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        character = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        RaycastHit grounded;
        isgrounded = Physics.Raycast(character.position, Vector3.down, out grounded, checkdistance);
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        character.velocity = new Vector3((Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * characterSpeed, character.velocity.y, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * characterSpeed);
 
        if (isgrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumping();
        }
    }
   
    void jumping()
    {
        character.velocity = new Vector3(character.velocity.x, jumpPower * gravity, character.velocity.z);
 
        if (character.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            character.velocity = new Vector3(character.velocity.x, jumpPower * gravity, character.velocity.z);
        }
        else if (character.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            character.velocity = new Vector3(character.velocity.x, jumpPower * gravity / 2, character.velocity.z);
        }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that jumping() only gets called when you start jumping. After that, isgrounded=false, so no more calls to jumping() will get made, hence the lack of control.

As for the actual physics calls, maybe something like this would work for you:

```
start(){
    bool jumped;  //differentiates between jumps and falling without jumping
...}

update(){
    if (isgrounded){  //end jump
        jumped=false;
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isgrounded){
        character.velocity = new Vector3(character.velocity.x, jumpPower, character.velocity.z);
        jumped=true;
    }

    //add gravity force every tick
    if (!isgrounded){
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && jumped){
            character.velocity = new Vector3(character.velocity.x, character.velocity.y+(gravity/2), character.velocity.z);
        else
            character.velocity = new Vector3(character.velocity.x, character.velocity.y+gravity, character.velocity.z);
    }
}
```